# Error: Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list mysql

Tags: mysql

My db is MyISAM.

I have set the columns to this in the db. 
artikel to VARCHAR(200)
ingress to VARCHAR(300)
texten to TEXT

And I have run this for FULLTEXT to work.

```
ALTER TABLE produkt ADD FULLTEXT(artikel, ingress, texten)
```

And in my .asp page I have this select.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM produkt WHERE MATCH (artikel, ingress, texten) AGAINST ('träbord');" 
set rs = conn.Execute (sql)
```

And I get the error:

```
`Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list`
```

So where do I go wrong? Any input really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Simply try to check is FULLTEXT indexes created:
`SHOW INDEX FROM yourtable;`

Also try to check is `keys` enabled for this table.

Comment: Thanks. When I show index it has only a primary key on the "produkt_id" column. How do I set INDEXes for the columns "artikel, ingress, texten" ? Just take alter table and check "Primary Key" on the columns, or?

Comment: SOLVED - Ok, so I added index to the columns and now it works, good!

Comment: Ok. I will write as answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Little step by step "guide" to check is with your fulltext indexes was created:

- check is FULLTEXT indexes created:
  `SHOW INDEX FROM yourtable;`
- check is keys enabled for this table.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ALTER TABLE product ADD FULLTEXT(name, short_description, full_description);

SELECT
  *
FROM laptopsaleservices.product 
WHERE
    MATCH(name, short_description, full_description) 
    AGAINST('Laptop'  IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32951576)